# Setting up node, no connection when announce ip address to peers

Tags: blockchain, full-node, peers, ardor

I want to announce my host name when running node. When I set nxt.myAddress=hostname or IPaddress, there are no connection to peers. But when I keep it empty everything is fine.

Comment: Problem solved. Port 27876, 27874 was blocked by ISP.